# External css not working in Broadleaf Email Templates

Tags: css, spring, broadleaf-commerce

I am using a custom email template in broadleaf. In that I am unable to use external css file.It's only allowing inline css. Is it will function like that or Is i am doing anything wrong.

This is how i am referring my css file

Both are not working.Kindly Have your say on this friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the email client will block external links and therefore your mail will not appear as you think it should. So its better you write the inline css for emailer.